# How to select a choice by pressing keys in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

[Problematic code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PBJw.png)
I try running the code "! accelerate config" and its choice need to be selected.
How do I press a key inside the code cell to select a choice?

I expect the solution or alternative solution of this problem.